# Jquery mouse hover callback is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have SVG circle element created in d3.

`<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="50" id="tooltip_area" stroke-width="0.6" style="fill: none; stroke: white;"></circle>`

I am trying to create mouse hover effect on this circle but the event is never triggered.

Here is the hovering code-

```
$('#tooltip_area').mouseover(function(event) {
  div.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", .9);
  div.html('Hi, This is Sample Text')
    .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
    .style("top", (event.pageY + 28) + "px");
});
```

I am not sure why the hovering code is not getting triggered

Comment: div.transition();  is div defined? what says your console?

Comment: waht does div refers to ? Post your whole code !

Comment: Mixing D3 and jQuery is **never** a good idea. Despite that, the code in your question does work: https://jsfiddle.net/ck3ojkbu/1/ Having said that, I just voted to close this question: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used D3 events instead of jquery events and it worked. As suggested by @gerardo-furtado in the comments, mixing jquery and D3 is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
hover
```

event for hover effect . Here is sample of how hover event works

```
$(".area").hover(function(){
    //This function executes when your mouse pointer enters the area.
    alert("You entered.");
},
function(){
    // This function executes when your mouse pointer leaves the area.
    alert("You left.");
});
```